# How to create href link that contains php + Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to protect some pdf files with password, using an onclick functions as shown in the code below

What I am trying to achieve here:

If the user inserted the correct ID, the script gives him the corresponding href link for his pdf file that should contains:

certificates/First_Last_ID.pdf

where "First" & "Last" are php variables, and the php variable ID =  the js var truePassword

Ex. If I clicked on the row of Jon Doe and inserted the correct password AAA0000

I get the following link:

```
window.location.href = '/certificates/Jon_Doe_AAA000.pdf';
```

Achieving this requires adding some variables in the link name, maybe!

Please Advice

```
<html>
    <body>  
        <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","x","y","z");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Academy");



            // Fetching Data from MySql
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['First'] . " " . $row['Last'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Program'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Date Accredited'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Grade'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='myFun(event);validate()'><img src='../SVG/certificate_logo.svg' /><span id='ID' style='display:none;'>" . $row['ID'] ."</span></a>" . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }

            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>

        <script>
        var truePassword;
        var password;

        function myFun(e){

            truePassword = (e.target.nextSibling.innerText);

        }

        function validate(){

            password = prompt('Enter Your Course Reservation ID  (Case Sensitive)', 'YYY0000');

            if (password==truePassword) {

              window.location.href = '/certificates/<?php echo  $row['First']."_".$row['Last'] ?>.pdf'; //relative to domain

            }else{
                alert ("Wrong ID");
                return;
               }    
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your $row is in while loop how can you get it outside of while loop window.location.href = '/certificates/<?php echo  $row['First']."_".$row['Last'] ?>.pdf'; //relative to domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the last "td" with the following

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='myFun(event);validate(this.id)' id='" . $row['First'] . "_" . $row['Last'] . "'><img src='../SVG/certificate_logo.svg' /><span id='ID' style='display:none;'>" . $row['ID'] ."</span></a>" . "</td>";
```

Try this

```
<script>
    var truePassword;
    var password;

    function myFun(e){

        truePassword = (e.target.nextSibling.innerText);

    }

    function validate(clicked_ele_id){

        password = prompt('Enter Your Course Reservation ID  (Case Sensitive)', 'YYY0000');

        if (password==truePassword) {

            window.location.href = '/certificates/' + clicked_ele_id + '_' + password + '.pdf'; //relative to domain

        }else{
            alert ("Wrong ID");
            return;
        }    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: gives me   /certificates/_.pdf

Comment: it brought me certificates/Jon_Doe.pdf without the _AAA0000

Comment: add "password" variable to the line. I have updated it in the answer. Have a look of it.

Comment: I already added it in the id='" . $row['First'] . "_" . $row['Last'] . "_" . $row['ID'] . "

Comment: currently promoting ID is case sensitive, How can I cancel this to let user insert it without caring about upper and lower case?

Comment: Use toLowerCase() method to compare the two strings like

if (password.toLowerCase()==truePassword.toLowerCase()) {

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the PHP variables in the href:

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='".$row['First']."_".$row['Last']."_".$row['ID'].".pdf'";
```

Comment: Can you pull data from your SQL table at all? Looks like that's most important.

Comment: Yes I can, It appears normally and correctly in my html table

Comment: Strange. It may help when you create the desired string (your generated filename) outside of the function, does it?

Comment: Then I don't there's a gentle other way besides AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an AJAX call for this. That way you also keep your password checking server side.

Comment: i am not that familiar with AJAX :(